# connection timeout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, connection

i build a web application and every thing works fine . but after i put it on real work i got a problem

after about 30 minutes working in it any connection will be loading and then through an exception :
request time out.

so i have to restart the server or restart the iis site to access the code again ?

why is that happened and how to fix it.

I use this connection class to connect to the database in the whole code :

```
public class Connection
{
    public static SqlConnection Open()
    {
        try
        {
            string ConStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SARC.mdf;Integrated Security=True; Max Pool Size=100; User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            con.Open();
            return con;
        }
        catch (SqlException odbcEx)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static SqlConnection Open(string ConStr)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            con.Open();
            return con;
        }
        catch (SqlException odbcEx)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void Close(SqlConnection ConStr)
    {
        try
        {
            ConStr.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException odbcEx)
        {
        }
    }

    public static SqlDataReader Query(string query, bool isreader)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
            return rd;

        }
        catch (SqlException odbcEx)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static SqlConnection con;
    public static int Query(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            con = (con == null ? new SqlConnection() : con);
            if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                con = Open();

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            int result = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (SqlException odbcEx)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

how can i fix this problem ??? plz help

Comment: so your server is running a thread that has a really long life span? something like a worker thread?

Comment: i dont know exactly its just stop after several time and need to restart the server to solve it

Comment: You haven't answer my question. Are you running a worker thread on the server?

Comment: what that mean ? and i guess not

Comment: Did you spawn any thread that will live for more than 30 min. Something like Send an email every 5 min.

Comment: no and all my connection in the web application are using this code up there and there is no internet access or any thing like this

Comment: not sure if this is the issue, but .Close() should always be in finally block instead of inside try block, and you need to make sure you close the connection after you are done with it